# How do I create a complete function for Apply promo code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an Apply promo code function on the checkout page. So I have successfully made a function where you can click on "Apply a promo code" text and a text field will open with "Apply" button. The user can then promo code and click on Apply to avail the promo. Now what I want to further achieve is once the user insert the coupon and click on apply button the input field and button should be replaced by: "Promo Code: Welcome25" and the delete favicon, and switch back to apply a promo code phase, and by clicking on the actual code he can again edit it with the input and apply button.

Can someone help me with the already code, please?

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<!-- START OF PROMO CODE -->
<div class="mt-3 text-center">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="promo-code">Apply a promo code</a>
</div>
<div id="promo-box">
<span class="col-9 float-left pl-0 pr-0">
<input type="text" class="checkout-promo-code-input" placeholder="Enter promo code">
</span>
<span class="col-3 float-left">
<button class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
</span>
</div>
<div class="mt-3 float-left promo-edit">
Promo Code:&nbsp; <a href=""><u>WELCOME25</u></a>
</div>
<div class="mt-3 float-right">
<a href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt trash-checkout"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.trash-checkout {
color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.trash-checkout:hover {
color: #dc3545;
}

.promo-edit {
font-weight: 600;
color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
font-size: 15px;
}

.promo-edit a {
color: #000000;
}

#promo-code {
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
}

#promo-box {
display: none;
}

input.checkout-promo-code-input {
color: #333333 !important;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
border: 2px solid #e0e6e8;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400 !important;
height: 35px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 10px;

}

input.checkout-promo-code-input:focus {
border-color: #25c16f;
outline: 0;
box-shadow: none;
border-bottom: solid 2px #25c16f;
}
```

JS:

```
/* Promo Code onClick function on Checkout Page */
$("#promo-code").click(function(){
document.getElementById("promo-code").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("promo-box").style.display = "block";
});
```

https://www.bootply.com/spq1CDfBxB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty value to your input:

```
<input type="text" class="checkout-promo-code-input" placeholder="Enter promo code" value="">
```

Then you need to apply the promo text to the value, so that if the promo code changes it is dynamically picked up - this is done by simply adding the following to your javascript.

```
$(".checkout-promo-code-input").val($(".promo-edit a").text());
```

https://www.bootply.com/zOOExLoE0s

Comment: Issues with this are I can see WELCOME25 preloaded when I click on the Apply promo for the first time. Promo Code:  WELCOME25 and the delete icon is showing from the start of the function.

Comment: @BillNathan I have updated my fiddle link. You can check it now.

Comment: @VirenPanchal I can't see any fiddle URL?

Comment: @BillNathan. My edited post is pending for "peer review". So here is the link in the comment. https://www.bootply.com/L6RGZOIuuo

Comment: Can you possibly hide this? http://prntscr.com/mi1s2l when the code is loaded and only show when clicked on "Apply". Also remove the preloaded value in input field?

Comment: @BillNathan Have you checked the updated fiddle? https://www.bootply.com/L6RGZOIuuo

Comment: @VirenPanchal I have achieved the task. Thanks for your help. How do I mark it completed or close the thread? I'm new to the stack overflow :)

Comment: @BillNathan It's nice to hear that you achieved your desired task. You are most welcome anytime. To close this thread and mark this question as "answered", you have to click on the Up Arrow and Right tick mark below to mark as accepted answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this, button should be replaced by: "Promo Code: Welcome25", you have to give ID to your button tag.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="applybtn">Apply</button>
```

and then you click Apply, Button value will be replaced by below code.

```
$("#applybtn").html('Promo Code: '+$(".promo-edit a").text());
```

https://www.bootply.com/L6RGZOIuuo

Comment: I think you guys are misunderstanding me. What I want is on Applying the promo code, then input field and button should hide and text should replace the whole place "Promo Code: ABC"     - Remove coupon icon. Refer: https://prnt.sc/mi0ihc

Comment: @BillNathan I have updated fiddle link again. https://www.bootply.com/L6RGZOIuuo  To show promo code when clicked on "Apply", I have added  `id="codediv" style="display:none;"` to the promo code display div and by default it will not display.  Then in promo-code onClick function, added `$("#codediv").show();` to show that code display div. I have also removed the preloaded code value from input field. and put condition that if input text value is NULL, then nothing will happen when pressing APPLY button.

Comment: @BillNathan Hey buddy. It's nice to hear that you achieved your desired task. You are most welcome anytime. To close this thread and mark this question as "answered", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577400/how-do-i-create-a-complete-function-for-apply-promo-code/54578978#54578978 , Here you have to click on the Up Arrow and Right tick mark below to mark as accepted answer. thanks.